# Ruby equivalent of Node .toString('ascii')

Tags: node.js, ruby

I am struggling with converting a Node application to Ruby. I have a Buffer of integers that I need to encode as an ASCII string.

In Node this is done like this:

```
const a = Buffer([53, 127, 241, 120, 57, 136, 112, 210, 162, 200, 111, 132, 46, 146, 210, 62, 133, 88, 80, 97, 58, 139, 234, 252, 246, 19, 191, 84, 30, 126, 248, 76])
const b = a.toString('hex')
// b = "357ff178398870d2a2c86f842e92d23e855850613a8beafcf613bf541e7ef84c"
const c = a.toString('ascii') 
// c = '5qx9\bpR"Ho\u0004.\u0012R>\u0005XPa:\u000bj|v\u0013?T\u001e~xL'
```

I want to get the same output in Ruby but I don't know how to convert `a` to `c`. I used `b` to validate that `a` is parsed the same in Ruby and Node and it looks like it's working.

```
a = [53, 127, 241, 120, 57, 136, 112, 210, 162, 200, 111, 132, 46, 146, 210, 62, 133, 88, 80, 97, 58, 139, 234, 252, 246, 19, 191, 84, 30, 126, 248, 76].pack('C*')
b = a.unpack('H*') 
# ["357ff178398870d2a2c86f842e92d23e855850613a8beafcf613bf541e7ef84c"]
# c = ???
```

I have tried serveral things, virtually all of the unpack options, and I also tried using the encode function but I lack the understanding of what the problem is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay well I am not that familiar with Node.js but you can get fairly close with some basic understandings:

Node states:

> 'ascii' - For 7-bit ASCII data only. This encoding is fast and will strip the high bit if set.

**Update** After rereading the nod.js description I think it just means it will drop 127 and only focus on the first 7 bits so this can be simplified to:

```
def node_js_ascii(bytes) 
  bytes.map {|b| b % 128 }
    .reject(&127.method(:==))
    .pack('C*')
    .encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
end
node_js_ascii(a)
#=>  #=> "5qx9\bpR\"Ho\u0004.\u0012R>\u0005XPa:\vj|v\u0013?T\u001E~xL"
```

Now the only differences are that node.js uses "\u000b" to represent a vertical tab and ruby uses "\v" and that ruby uses uppercase characters for unicode rather than lowercase ("\u001E" vs "\u001e") (you could handle this if you so chose)

**Please note** This form of encoding is not reversible due to the fact that you have characters that are greater than 8 bits in your byte array.

**TL;DR** (previous explanation and solution only works up to 8 bits)

Okay so we know the max supported decimal is 127 (`"1111111".to_i(2)`) and that node will strip the high bit if set meaning [I am assuming] 241 (an 8 bit number will become 113 if we strip the high bit)

With that understanding we can use:

```
a = [53, 127, 241, 120, 57, 136, 112, 210, 162, 200, 111, 132, 46, 146, 210, 62, 133, 88, 80, 97, 58, 139, 234, 252, 246, 19, 191, 84, 30, 126, 248, 76].map do |b| 
    b < 128 ? b : b - 128
end.pack('C*')
#=> "5\x7Fqx9\bpR\"Ho\x04.\x12R>\x05XPa:\vj|v\x13?T\x1E~xL"
```

Then we can encode that as `UTF-8` like so:

```
a.encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
#=> "5\u007Fqx9\bpR\"Ho\u0004.\u0012R>\u0005XPa:\vj|v\u0013?T\u001E~xL"
```

but there is still is still an issue here.

It seems Node.js also ignores the Delete (127) when it converts to 'ascii' (I mean the high bit is set but if we strip it then it is 63 ("?") which doesn't match the output) so we can fix that too

```
 a = [53, 127, 241, 120, 57, 136, 112, 210, 162, 200, 111, 132, 46, 146, 210, 62, 133, 88, 80, 97, 58, 139, 234, 252, 246, 19, 191, 84, 30, 126, 248, 76].map do |b| 
    b < 127 ? b : b - 128
end.pack('C*')
#=> "5\xFFqx9\bpR\"Ho\x04.\x12R>\x05XPa:\vj|v\x13?T\x1E~xL"
a.encode(Encoding::UTF_8, undef: :replace, replace: '')
#=> "5qx9\bpR\"Ho\u0004.\u0012R>\u0005XPa:\vj|v\u0013?T\u001E~xL"
```

Now since 127 - 128 = -1  (negative signed bit) becomes "\xFF"   an undefined character in UTF-8 so we add `undef: :replace` what to do when the character is undefined use replace and we add `replace: ''` to replace with nothing.

Comment: All though this seems to be a working solution I ended up not having to use it. Still I can verify that this works.

Comment: @PabloJomer I honestly would not recommend using it simply for the fact that it can not be converted back unless all characters are less than 8 bits and not 127

Comment: I understood that. The reason we needed it was because we needed to compare this string that was generated by a system that was not under our control. But it turned out that we could use another method where this was not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the help I bet it will help some one in the future.